# Identify the SNS topic that my SQS is receiving messages from

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I've created a SQS and it's subscribed to 3 different SNS topics.

I've also setup a DLQ for the SQS queue so all the unprocessed messages are going to the DLQ.

I now have thousands of messages in the DLQ and I want to find out which SNS Topic those messages are from.

Is there a straight forward of way of getting this information from the AWS console? If not, how do I get it?